# Undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for Warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warden

I have a Helper module as follows. The module uses warden.

```
module V0
  module Api
    # @private
    module Helpers
      def warden
        env['warden']
      end

      # Used to require an authenticated user for a particular action.
      def protected!
        warden.authenticate!
      end

      def current_user
        warden.user
      end

      def parse_json_body
        request.body.rewind
        request_body = current_user ? current_user.keychain_replace(request.body.read) : request.body.read
        @parsed_body = JSON.parse(request_body, symbolize_names: true)
        params.update @parsed_body
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The module parses a request. In the line

```
request_body = current_user ? current_user.keychain_replace(request.body.read) : request.body.read
```

I tried to check if current user is set and get request_body accordingly. However I get the following errors.

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # (eval):2:in `method_missing'
     # ./app/api/v0/helpers.rb:11:in `warden'
     # ./app/api/v0/helpers.rb:23:in `current_user'
     # ./app/api/v0/helpers.rb:37:in `parse_json_body'
```

If no current user is set then it should have set

```
request_body = request.body.read
```

but I don't get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
request_body = current_user ? current_user.key ..
```

try

```
request_body = !current_user.nil? ? current_user.key ..
```

That would get a true/false response to evaluate.. I put the ! in to preserve the order of your arguments.

This is a bit of a guess, but I think it's evaluating a nil, rather than looking for false properties..

Comment: That didn't work either. Trying to use current_user.nil? itself causes the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in your `warden` method. The `env` variable is `nil` there. Check if  your module is loaded in correctly.